# Div slidingUp issues

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div **.adsearch-panel** which contain some select boxes and text boxes. I want to hide it when click outside the div. For this, I'm using;

```
$(document).on({
    mouseup:
    function(e){
        var container = $('.adsearch-panel');

        if(container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            container.slideUp(200);
        }
    }
});
```

The above coding is working well but even if I click any elements inside that div such as select boxes, still its sliding up. I wanna keep it visible if the div or anything inside the div is clicked.

Please help me fix this.

Thank you and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your `on` method is not correct, should be:

```
$('document').on("mouseup", function (e) {
    var container = $('.adsearch-panel');

    if(container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.slideUp(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, `$('document')`  should be `$(document)`

Comment: Thank you, I did like this, but still the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `e.target` here is refering to the `document`. You have to put a `stopPropagation` for clicking on the div:

```
$('.adsearch-panel').on('mouseup', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ebixar/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on('click', function(ev) {
        var myCN = ev.target.className;
        if (myCN !== 'adsearch-panel') {
            $('.adsearch-panel').hide();
        }
    });

    $('.showAdsearch').on('click', function( e ) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.adsearch-panel').show();
    });
});
```